# DELETE method requires query parameter instead of path parameter in next.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, next.js

I am creating a CRUD in API,
but the delete does not seems to work properly.
I get a response from this

```
http://localhost:3000/api/admin/categories?id=1
```

and not from this

```
http://localhost:3000/api/admin/categories/1
```

this is the code in next.js:

```
export default async (req, res) => {
  const {
    query: { id },
    method,
  } = req;


  switch (method) {
    case "DELETE":
      return res.status(200).json({
        success: true,
        id: id,
      });
    }
```

in React:

```
 axios.delete(`http://localhost:3000/api/admin/categories/`, {id: 1})
```

The same situation is also with "PUT" method

Folder Directory:

```
api
|
---admin
--------categories
--------index.js
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create API Routes such as DELETE, PUT ( they require /id as path parameter), you should create a separate file in that folder.

Like this:

```
api
|
---admin
--------categories
--------index.js
--------[id].js
```

And in the [id].js file:

```
export default function handler(req, res) {
  const { id } = req.query;
  if (req.method === "DELETE") {
    res.end(`Category: ${id}`);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use this one.

```
 const urlParams = new URL(req.url);
 console.log({urlParams})
const serviceId = urlParams.searchParams.get("serviceId");
```

make sure your request url is like this "http://localhost:3000/api/service?serviceId=64a0571eb5c6d3cb44e1f536" and you can modify serviceId as you wish.

I will post next js DELETE function which works for all versions in nextjs.

export async function DELETE(req: NextRequest, res: NextResponse) {
await connectDB();

```
//http://localhost:3000/api/service?serviceId=64a0571eb5c6d3cb44e1f536

 const urlParams = new URL(req.url);
 console.log({urlParams})
const serviceId = urlParams.searchParams.get("serviceId");


if (!serviceId) {
  return new NextResponse(
    JSON.stringify({ message: 'Service ID is required' }),
    { status: 400, headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' } }
  );
}

const service = await Service.findById(serviceId);
if (!service) {
  return new NextResponse(
    JSON.stringify({ message: "Service not found" }),
    { status: 404, headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' } }
  );
}



const deletedService = await service.deleteOne();

if (deletedService) {
  return NextResponse.json({ message: `Deleted successfully ${deletedService._id}` });
} else {
  return new NextResponse(
    JSON.stringify({ message: 'Unexpected error. Please try again.' }),
    { status: 500, headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' } }
  );
}
```

}